# What is the resolution to this "No Instance" error?

Tags: haskell

I have created new type describing Binary Tree

```
data BinTree a = Null | Num a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
deriving (Show)
```

And have created the following function:

```
treehandle :: BinTree a -> Bool
treehandle a = True
```

to check at least inputing values.

When I input value Null, program outputs result successfully, but I can't input binary tree. I try thus:

```
treehandle (5 (Null) (Null))
```

but obtain:

```
<interactive>:66:13:
No instance for (Num (BinTree a1 -> BinTree a2 -> BinTree a0))
  (maybe you haven't applied enough arguments to a function?)
  arising from the literal ‘5’
In the expression: 5
In the first argument of ‘treehandle’, namely ‘(5 (Null) (Null))’
In the expression: treehandle (5 (Null) (Null))
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the value constructor's name

```
treehandle (Num 5 (Null) (Null))
```

Comment: Yes! That's right! Can you explain why I must write constructor's name?

Comment: Short and sweet for explaining how to fix the problem. The other half of the question is "how does the error I got correspond to the code I typed?". There the answer is that `5 (Null) (Null)` is an expression that tries to apply the function `5` to the arguments `(Null)` and `(Null)` -- but `5` is not a function.

Comment: @AyratArifullin Try asking yourself that same question for the empty tree case. If you didn't type the constructor's name, namely, `Null`, what do you think you would type instead? (There are other good reasons, too, but that one should get you started thinking in the right direction.)

Comment: Adding to @DanielWagner, imagine you have another structure composed of two BinTree, `data Bleh a = Bleh a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)`.

Answer (score 6):

I would find a different naming for the data constructors if I was you. `Num` is also the name of a type class, this can be very confusing when looking at error messages.

Also `deriving Show` is not correctly indented, and you forgot the data constructor in `treehandle (5 (Null) (Null))`. Here is a working version.

```
data BinTree a = Leaf | Node a (BinTree a) (BinTree a) deriving Show

treehandle :: BinTree a -> Bool
treehandle _ = True

test = treehandle $ Node 5 Leaf Leaf
```

`treehandle` wants a value of type `BinTree a` and all you gave it was an `Int` and two empty `BinTree's`, it actually tried to apply the `Int` with the two empty `BinTree's` and failed. You have to make a `Node` to get a single `BinTree a` which you can pass to `treehandle`

Answer (score 0):

I thank for your replies. I appreciate it. Haskell is "wild" language being mix of Lisp and Prolog. Gradually I begin to get used to it. I would share with my results. So, that's **BinTree** declaration:

```
data BinTree a = Leaf | Val a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
 deriving (Show)
```

It resembles on Prolog *unification algorithm* - I mean about definition of "reverse" as below:

```
reverse :: BinTree a -> BinTree a
reverse (Val a1 (a2) (a3)) = (Val a1 (reverse a3) (reverse a2))
reverse Leaf = Leaf
```

It works!

Comment: The feature you're describing here is pattern matching. It does indeed resemble unification at times and is immensely useful in defining simple, readable functions.